# remove double quotes in each row (csv writer)

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm writing API results to CSV file in python 3.7. Problem is it adds double quotes ("") to each row when it writes to file.

I'm passing format as csv to API call, so that I get results in csv format and then I'm writing it to csv file, store to specific location.
Please suggest if there is any better way to do this.

Here is the sample code..

```
    with open(target_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf8') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\"')
        for line in rec.split('\r\n'):
            writer.writerow([line])
```

when I use `escapechar='\"'` it adds (`"`) at the of every column value.

here is sample records..

```
2264855868",42.38454",-71.01367",07/15/2019 00:00:00",07/14/2019 20:00:00"
2264855868",42.38454",-71.01367",07/15/2019 01:00:00",07/14/2019 21:00:00"
```

Comment: if you get it as csv file then write it with `open(filename, 'wb').write(rec)` without `csv.writer()`. You use `csv.writer` when you have data as Python's list.

Comment: thank you very much.. this works perfectly for me..

    req = requests.get(url=api_base_url, params=params, headers=headers)
    with open(target_file_name, 'wb') as csvfile:
        csvfile.write(req.content)

Is it going to make any difference in performance or something.. just wanted to be sure which method is good to go with.

Comment: API gives string/bytes which you can write directly in file. With `csv.writer` you would have to convert string/bytes to Python's data using `csv.reader` and then convert it back to  string/bytes with `csv.writer` - so there is no sens to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API gives string/bytes which you can write directly in file.

```
data = request.get(..).content
open(filename, 'wb').write(data)
```

---

With `csv.writer` you would have to convert string/bytes to Python's data using `csv.reader` and then convert it back to string/bytes with `csv.writer` - so there is no sense to do it.

---

The same method should work if API send any file:  `JSON`, `CSV`, `XML`, `PDF`, images, audio, etc.

For bigger files you could use `chunk`/`stream` in `requests`. Doc: [requests - Advanced Usage](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Have you tried removing the backward-slash from `escapechar='\"'`? It shouldn't be necessary, since you are using single quotes for the string.</strike>

**EDIT:** From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

> A one-character string used by the writer to escape the delimiter if quoting is set to QUOTE_NONE and the quotechar if doublequote is False. On reading, the escapechar removes any special meaning from the following character.

And the delimeter:

> A one-character string used to separate fields. It defaults to ','

So it is going to escape the delimeter (`,`) with whatever you set as the `escapechar`, in this case `,`

If you don't want any escape, try leaving it empty

Comment: Yes, tried removing backward-slash (escapechar='"') but no difference in result.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import codecs

def find_replace(file, search_characters, replace_with):
    text = codecs.open(file, "r", "utf-8-sig")
    text = ''.join([i for i in text]).replace(
        search_characters, replace_with)
    x = codecs.open(file, "w", "utf-8-sig")
    x.writelines(text)
    x.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file = "target_file_path"
    search_characters = '"'
    replace_with = ''

    find_replace(file, search_characters, replace_with)
```

output:

```sh
2264855868,42.38454,-71.01367,07/15/2019 00:00:00,07/14/2019 20:00:00
2264855868,42.38454,-71.01367,07/15/2019 01:00:00,07/14/2019 21:00:00
```